# Monitoring Application on Production with JProfiler

Tags: performance, jvm, profiling, jprofiler

Currently we have been facing some issues in production where the application is throwing OutOfMemoryError, in order to identify what is the current cause we have ordered JProfiler and we are planning to buy the licence, the question here is, is it needed to use a JProfiler agent into the prod server as per the JProfiler architecture ? will it harm the performance of the app in prod ? is this agent mandatory ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have to add the profiling agent by passing the `-agentlib` VM parameter as given by the remote integration wizard (Session->Integration Wizards->New remote integration) in order to profile a JVM.

The performance impact depends on the profiling settings. If you do not start allocation recording and use sampling as the method call recording type, the overhead will typically not be more than a few percent.

However, if you just need to investigate an OutOfMemoryError, you can pass the VM parameter

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

and open the [HPROF snapshot](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/heapWalker/hprofSnapshots.html) in the JProfiler GUI.